# Subclassed UITableViewCell and removing a subview programmatically - how to get it to resize?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a subclassed UTableViewCell that is laid out in the picture below.  Everything is wired up with AutoLayout constraints (although still work in progress).

Basically, this custom cell is working as expected.  However, I would like to use this same cell, but without the UIImageView for some indexPath.rows.

I'm trying something like below:

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BaseDiaryCell"];
[cell.photoImageView removeFromSuperview];
```

and hoped that the cell should shrink because I removed the UIImageView from the cell, but it stays the same size with a gap between the "MainText" UILabel and the 3 UIButton at the bottom.

Is what I'm doing possible?  Is there another way to remove the UIImageView and have the cell automagically shrink down to reflect the changed layout?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. Thats not possible. Auto layout constraints are only used to detect the Rect of the object and animation context.

I think the best possible way is to create a new cell with no ImageView, so there will be two cells, one with the image view and other without. You can use cell identifiers to distinguish between them.

You will also need to use login in `height for row` method in your data source.

Comment: did you try to set the width and height of imageview to 0 instead of removing from SuperView? Try to set frame as CGRectZero. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Why add extra memory?

Comment: I disagree, I think it's possible.

Comment: That's true, but if he still wants to persist with this design and also need solution, then he can set the width and height of image to 0 and set row height also :)

Comment: @JuJoDi Unless he changes constraints runtime i.e. before instantiating, I don't know how it is possible. Please provide solution or reference. Once instantiated, the constraints help to decide the frame and their work is done. After that whatever you mutilate or so doesn't make effect. This is as per my knowledge. Let me know.

Comment: @sanjaymathad check my earlier comment. I would like to know your solution.

Comment: You can setup constraints that would automatically reduce the size of a view when a subview is removed. You would need a low priority constraint (say 20 points with a priority of 245) between the label and the buttons. Once the subview is gone (along with its constraints) this constraint would take over and shrink the superview. However, this isn't practical in a table view cell. You still need to return a different size for the cell, and, more importantly, because of cell reuse, you would have to add the view back for the rows where you want that subview. Your answer a good solution.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda. If he wants to persist with the same design, one solution is to set the frame of the imageview to CGRectZero. Since the lower views are dependent on the imageview frame, they will position automatically. He also has to set the height of the row for the cell in which imageview is hidden. :)

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, I'm aware of this solutions (Priorities). However, due to the same reason I dint suggest it: Can't be used in tabeviews (row Height etc.)